# 1.90 GHz dualcore with Turbo Boost up to 3 GHz - good enough to run VMs?

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vn-duo/svd1121z9e

Core i7-3517U 1.90-3.00 GHz dualcore, 8gb RAM, 256Gb SSD

I'm about to buy the above laptop as a demo machine as I need to demo on client site, but I want to know if it's a good enough processor to run VM's via hyper-v using Windows 8.

The vm's will be windows 2008 running share-point with SQL server on one VM so I expect them to be resource-hungry

Comment: An all in one install of Sharepoint?  SQL on same VM?

Comment: Yes all on one VM. just for demo's and it's about 50 gbs

Comment: It's probably worth noting what kind of hardware you're running right now. If your VM demo is 50gb and runs well with 2 cores and 4gb-6gb RAM allocated, then you should be totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

You havent put enough information in your question.

With what I am seeing, I am going to say you will want a machine with more memory, which that machine does not support.  Windows Server 2008 has a recommended minimum of 2 GB of RAM.  However, with other services running like SQL server, sharepoint, and whatnot, I wouldnt run it with less than 4.  Since you said you running more than 1 VM thats 8 GB of RAM right there.

Not to mention 256 GB of storage is small.  Depending on the size of each OS footprint, pagefile, applications, and data, you could be bumping up against, or exceeding that size.

Answer (score 0):

As @Keltari notes RAM is going to be an issue depending on what you need the VM to demonstrate.  For doing some training, I easily run Server 2008R2, SharePoint 2010 and SQL in one VM with a Core 2 Quad and 8GB of RAM. It works well for the training but can be a bit slow at times. VM is on an external USB 3.0 drive.  Also, you may be light on processors to assign to the VM but again, depends what you are doing.  However, it is worth at least trying and seeing what performance is like. As to space, I would have the VM on an external or second hard drive or SSD. If a hard drive, look at 7200RPM with a alarge cache.  Western Digital Black have worked well for me. If external, connect with USB 3.0 if possible, eSATA failing that and finally USB 2.0.  Avoid having it on the OS/Host drive.  Some laptops can swap the DVD/CD for a media bay which works well for running a VM.  I use one all the time and it works very well. [Newmodus](http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=2&zenid=7b4094149ba2509fcfaca5249cd5be23) has a number of options.

As to why put the VM on external or other storage, it addreses the largest bottleneck to running VMs.  Disk I/O  Microsoft talks about this a great deal as does VMware.  The root OS is also running on top of the Hyper-V virtualization layer.

Comment: Why would you want to put your VM files on slow external storage? If the laptop is being used as a client demo, I don't see why you'd have to worry about the host OS because it would be running the VM when it matters.

Comment: @Marcus Chan  see added comments in post

Comment: 8 gb's will be fine for ram the VM will only have one user.